# Apache Derby Embedded Mode and Multi-Threaded Connection Management

Tags: multithreading, jdbc, database-connection, derby

I am currently working on an application (whose logic and code I cannot put out here) that creates an embedded derby database and interacts with it using multiple threads to perform CRUD and SELECT operations.

Let's say the name of the embedded database is **bar** and the path to this database is **c:\foo\bar**

Multiple threads open a their **own connection** to **c:\foo\bar** and perform their respective operations against their own tables in the database. 
The connection to the database is abstracted out by a decorator that also maintains the last time the connection was accessed. 
If the last time the connection was accessed exceeds a particular threshold the database connection is shutdown and reaped.
There is a reaper thread that runs at a pre-defined scheduled interval and performs the reaping logic. As a part of the reaping logic it uses the following shutdown URL:

```
jdbc:derby:c:\foo\bar;shutdown=true
```

Any thread that attempts to perform a query against this database after the reaper thread has run fails with Derby error **8003** which indicates that there is no current connection.

So is it that in Derby embedded mode even though each thread has opened it's own connection; when the reaper thread runs it shuts down the entire database and any connections that were previously opened against this database **across all threads** are now in an invalid or closed state?

What are the best practices for using embedded derby within such applications?

Answer (score 1):

The `shutdown=true` attribute on the Derby JDBC Connection URL doesn't shut down the **connection**, it shuts down the **database**.

See: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefattrib16471.html

If you just want to shut down a **connection**, call `Connection.close()`